# fetching data not showing in table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap-table

I am creating a table and fetching data using Axios. However, I am not able to print the data – when I check, the data is being printed in the browser, but I am not able to print the particular data to a table format.

What should I change in my code?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", (req, res) => {
        res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => setUser({ ...user, data }))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3 className="text-primary">User List</h3>
      <Table
        variant="danger"
        striped
        bordered
        hover
        className="shadow-lg text-center"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {user?.data?.length > 0 &&
            user.data.map((user) => {
              return (
                <tr key={user.id}>
                  <td>{JSON.stringify(user.data["data"].id)}</td>
                  <td>{JSON.stringify(user.data["data"].name)}</td>
                  <td>{JSON.stringify(user.data["data"].username)}</td>
                  <td>{JSON.stringify(user.data["data"].email)}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
      {/* <div>{JSON.stringify(user.data["data"])}</div> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: user.data.id access like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => {
        setUser(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3 className="text-primary">User List</h3>
      <Table
        variant="danger"
        striped
        bordered
        hover
        className="shadow-lg text-center"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {user?.length > 0 &&
            user.map((userData) => {
              return (
                <tr key={userData.id}>
                  <td>{userData.id}</td>
                  <td>{userData.name}</td>
                  <td>{userData.username}</td>
                  <td>{userData.email}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
      {/* <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the useEffect code as follow.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((data) => setUser({ ...user, data }))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already know that calling this api will give you an array of users so you can initialise the state as empty array as:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

and when you are using `axios` then you don't have to use `res.json()`. `axios` will do it for you out of the box.

```
axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(({ data }) => setUsers(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

so, after getting data using `get` method of `axios` it will return you a promise and you can get data from its `data` property that is passed an first args. You can directly set state which will be an array of objects.

```
.then(({ data }) => setUsers(data))
```

Here I've destructed the object to get only the `data` property.

---

Since `users` will be an array of objects, so you don't have to do any check. You can directly use `user.id` to get the respective property.

[`Codesandbox link`](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-architecture-7drz37?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(({ data }) => setUsers(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3 className="text-primary">User List</h3>
      <Table
        variant="danger"
        striped
        bordered
        hover
        className="shadow-lg text-center"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.map((user) => {
            return (
              <tr key={user.id}>
                <td>{user.id}</td>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.username}</td>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
      {/* <div>{JSON.stringify(user.data["data"])}</div> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```